# Создание рамки вокруг контролов

Tags: wxwidgets, c++

Подскажите, как создать такую рамку с другими контролами внутри? Указал зеленой стрелкой на картинке.
wxRadioBox имеет такую же вокруг себя. Есть ли что-то подобное для других контролов? 
[image]

Comment: Вы можете рисовать на wxPanel все, что угодно. Наследуйтесь от класса, который хотите переделать, и перерисуйте его, как Вам будет удобно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение было простое, без создания новых классов, передать в конструктор layout'а

```
wxStaticBoxSizer *dialogSizer1 = new wxStaticBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL,this,"Operande 1");
```